# Displaying Groups of Multiple Items with same ID using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

The following solution is nearly perfect. But I discovered that some items have identical Scott numbers but no Minor field.

I need to display items with identical Scott #s that have different `<Title>` fields and data.

For example there are two stamps in Scott #s 3090 & 3152 but only one displays in the results. XSLT has to repeat stamps with identical Scott # but that do not have Minor variants

Here is the current XSLT:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="stamp-by-group" match="stamp" use="Group" />
 <xsl:key name="stamp-by-scott" match="stamp" use="concat(Group, '|', Scott)" />
 <xsl:key name="stamp-by-minor" match="stamp" use="concat(Group, '|', Scott, '|', Minor)" />

 <xsl:template match="/stamps">
 <xsl:copy>

 <xsl:for-each select="stamp[count(. | key('stamp-by-group', Group)[1]) = 1]">
 <StampGroup id="{Group}">
 <GroupTitle><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="Series"><Series><xsl:value-of select="Series" /></Series></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Issue"><Issue><xsl:value-of select="Issue" /></Issue>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <empty />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose></GroupTitle>

 <xsl:for-each select="key('stamp-by-group', Group)[count(. | key('stamp-by-scott', concat(Group, '|', Scott))[1]) = 1]">

 <stampvariants>   
 <xsl:apply-templates select="key('stamp-by-scott', concat(Group, '|', Scott))[count(. | key('stamp-by-minor', concat(Group, '|', Scott, '|', Minor))[1]) = 1]"/>
 </stampvariants>\
 </xsl:for-each>

 </StampGroup>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="stamp">       
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Scott"/>
    <Minor><xsl:value-of select="Minor" /></Minor>
     <xsl:copy-of select="Title"/>           
 </xsl:copy>

 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stamps>        
<stamp>
<Group>1</Group>
<Scott>3090</Scott>
<Title>32¢ Rural Free Delivery</Title>
</stamp>
<stamp>
<Group>1</Group>
<Scott>3090</Scott>
<Title>Pane of 20</Title>
</stamp>
<stamp>
<Group>2</Group>
<Scott>3091</Scott>
<Title>32¢ Robert E. Lee</Title>
<Issue>Riverboats</Issue>
</stamp>
<stamp>     
<Group>25</Group>       
<Scott>3133</Scott>     
<Title>32¢ Thornton Wilder</Title>      
<Series>Literary Arts</Series>      
</stamp>        
<stamp>     
<Group>26</Group>       
<Scott>3134</Scott>     
<Title>32¢ Charlie Chaplin</Title>      
</stamp>
<stamp>     
<Group>26</Group>       
<Scott>3135</Scott>     
<Title>32¢ Raoul Wallenberg</Title>     
</stamp>
<stamp>     
<Group>27</Group>       
<Scott>3136</Scott>     
<Title>Sheet of 15</Title>      
<Issue>The World of Dinosaurs</Issue>       
</stamp>        
<stamp>     
<Group>27</Group>       
<Scott>3136</Scott>     
<Minor>a</Minor>        
<Title>32¢ Ceratosaurus</Title>     
<Issue>The World of Dinosaurs</Issue>       
</stamp>        
<stamp>     
<Group>27</Group>       
<Scott>3136</Scott>     
<Minor>b</Minor>        
<Title>32¢ Camptosaurus</Title>     
<Issue>The World of Dinosaurs</Issue>       
</stamp>        
<stamp>     
<Group>27</Group>       
<Scott>3136</Scott>     
<Minor>c</Minor>        
<Title>32¢ Camarasaurus</Title>     
<Issue>The World of Dinosaurs</Issue>       
</stamp>
<stamp>
<Group>35</Group>
<Scott>3152</Scott>
<Title>32¢ Humphrey Bogart</Title>
<Series>Legends of Hollywood</Series>
</stamp>
<stamp>
<Group>35</Group>
<Scott/> 
<Title>Pane of 20</Title>
</stamp>
</stamps>
```

Note that Group 1 and Group 35 have identical Scott #s but no Minor variants. Titles for the Variants differ. The XSLT needs to loop through all Scott #s and Minor variants.

This is the current result:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <stamps>
 <StampGroup id="1">
  <GroupTitle>
     <empty/>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3090</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Rural Free Delivery</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>
 <StampGroup id="2">
  <GroupTitle>
     <Issue>Riverboats</Issue>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3091</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Robert E. Lee</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>
 <StampGroup id="25">
  <GroupTitle>
     <Series>Literary Arts</Series>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3133</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Thornton Wilder</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>
 <StampGroup id="26">
  <GroupTitle>
     <empty/>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3134</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Charlie Chaplin</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3135</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Raoul Wallenberg</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>
 <StampGroup id="27">
  <GroupTitle>
     <Issue>The World of Dinosaurs</Issue>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3136</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>Sheet of 15</Title>
     </stamp>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3136</Scott>
        <Minor>a</Minor>
        <Title>32¢ Ceratosaurus</Title>
     </stamp>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3136</Scott>
        <Minor>b</Minor>
        <Title>32¢ Camptosaurus</Title>
     </stamp>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3136</Scott>
        <Minor>c</Minor>
        <Title>32¢ Camarasaurus</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
</StampGroup>
<StampGroup id="35">
  <GroupTitle>
     <Series>Legends of Hollywood</Series>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3152</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Humphrey Bogart</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>
 </stamps>
```

This is the desired result:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <stamps>
 <StampGroup id="1">
  <GroupTitle>
     <empty/>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3090</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Rural Free Delivery</Title>
     </stamp>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3090</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>Pane of 20</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>

 <StampGroup id="2">
  <GroupTitle>
     <Issue>Riverboats</Issue>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3091</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Robert E. Lee</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>

 <StampGroup id="25">
  <GroupTitle>
     <Series>Literary Arts</Series>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3133</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Thornton Wilder</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>

 <StampGroup id="26">
  <GroupTitle>
     <empty/>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3134</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Charlie Chaplin</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3135</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Raoul Wallenberg</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>

 <StampGroup id="27">
  <GroupTitle>
     <Issue>The World of Dinosaurs</Issue>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3136</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>Sheet of 15</Title>
     </stamp>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3136</Scott>
        <Minor>a</Minor>
        <Title>32¢ Ceratosaurus</Title>
     </stamp>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3136</Scott>
        <Minor>b</Minor>
        <Title>32¢ Camptosaurus</Title>
     </stamp>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3136</Scott>
        <Minor>c</Minor>
        <Title>32¢ Camarasaurus</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
</StampGroup>

<StampGroup id="35">
  <GroupTitle>
     <Series>Legends of Hollywood</Series>
  </GroupTitle>
  <stampvariants>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3152</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>32¢ Humphrey Bogart</Title>
     </stamp>
     <stamp>
        <Scott>3152</Scott>
        <Minor/>
        <Title>Pane of 20</Title>
     </stamp>
  </stampvariants>
 </StampGroup>
 </stamps>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. I suggest you limit yourself  to one issue only, and explain what that issue is. There is only so much one can gather by eyeballing the result.

Comment: Items are grouped by the Group field. Then by Scott # and by Minor variant. I need to display Items that have identical Scott # that don't have Minor variants. Look at `<Scott>3090</Scott>`. Only one appears in the current results. But there are two items in the XML and both need to be displayed. Does that make it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="stamp-by-group" match="stamp" use="Group" />
<xsl:key name="stamp-by-scott" match="stamp" use="concat(Group, '|', Scott)" />
<xsl:key name="stamp-by-minor" match="stamp" use="concat(Group, '|', Scott, '|', Minor)" />

<xsl:template match="/stamps">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="stamp[count(. | key('stamp-by-group', Group)[1]) = 1]">
            <StampGroup id="{Group}">
                <GroupTitle><!-- immaterial for this answer --></GroupTitle>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('stamp-by-group', Group)[count(. | key('stamp-by-scott', concat(Group, '|', Scott))[1]) = 1]">
                    <stampvariants>   
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('stamp-by-scott', concat(Group, '|', Scott))[count(. | key('stamp-by-minor', concat(Group, '|', Scott, '|', Minor))[1]) = 1]">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="not(Minor)">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('stamp-by-minor', concat(Group, '|', Scott, '|', Minor))"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </stampvariants>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </StampGroup>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stamp">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Scott | Title"/>
        <Minor><xsl:value-of select="Minor" /></Minor>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which at this point might be more manageable if rewritten as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="stamp-by-group" match="stamp" use="Group" />
<xsl:key name="stamp-by-scott" match="stamp" use="concat(Group, '|', Scott)" />
<xsl:key name="stamp-by-minor" match="stamp" use="concat(Group, '|', Scott, '|', Minor)" />

<xsl:template match="/stamps">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="stamp[count(. | key('stamp-by-group', Group)[1]) = 1]" mode="group"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="stamp" mode="group">
    <StampGroup id="{Group}">
        <GroupTitle><!-- immaterial for this answer --></GroupTitle>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('stamp-by-group', Group)[count(. | key('stamp-by-scott', concat(Group, '|', Scott))[1]) = 1]" mode="scott"/>
    </StampGroup>
</xsl:template>     

<xsl:template match="stamp" mode="scott">
    <stampvariants>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('stamp-by-scott', concat(Group, '|', Scott))[count(. | key('stamp-by-minor', concat(Group, '|', Scott, '|', Minor))[1]) = 1]" mode="minor"/>
    </stampvariants>
</xsl:template>         

<xsl:template match="stamp" mode="minor">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(Minor)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('stamp-by-minor', concat(Group, '|', Scott, '|', Minor))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>                 

<xsl:template match="stamp">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Scott | Title"/>
        <Minor><xsl:value-of select="Minor" /></Minor>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```